# Do not output empty lines when using JsRender

Tags: node.js, template-engine, jsrender

I am using [JsRender](http://www.jsviews.com/#jsrapi) in `Node.js`.
If given an example data:

```
{
    "items": [
        {"name":"Alf", display:false},
        {"name":"Bruno", display:true}
    ]
}
```

And a template:

```
{{* index=0; }}
{{for items}}
{{if display}}
name[{{*: index; }}] = "{{: name }}";
{{* index++; }}
{{/if}}
{{/for}}
```

I get:

```
//empty line
//empty line
//empty line
//empty line
//empty line
name[0] = "Bruno";
//empty line
//empty line
//empty line
```

As you can see, there is crap loads of empty lines, for every line of the template where I don't output anything.
Is there a way to stop `JsRender` from outputting these empty lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JsRender will output whatever white-space characters are in the template.

It can't guess which ones you want and which you don't want. (To put it humorously, one could say: Put crap in, get crap out!!).

So for example:

```
{{for items}}{{:name}}{{/for}}
```

will output

```
"AlfBruno"
```

and

```
{{for items}}{{:name}} {{/for}}
```

will output

```
"Alf Bruno "
```

and

```
{{for items}}{{:name}}
{{/for}}
```

will output

```
"Alf\nBruno\n"
```

So if you don't want any newlines at all, you can write

```
{{* index=0; }}{{for items}}{{if display}}name[{{*: index; }}] = "{{:name}}";{{* index++; }}{{/if}}{{/for}}
```

or if you prefer

```
{{* index=0;
}}{{for items
}}{{if display
}}name[{{*: index; }}] = "{{:name}}";{{* index++;
}}{{/if}}{{/for}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and I understand this. However, it would be nice to not output new lines for lines in the template where I do not render anything. Otherwise it makes the output full of new-lines, or the template very difficult to read. It could be controlled with some kind of flag, similar to `views.settings.allowCode=true`. I could fork the project, work on this and submit a PR, if you are ok with this.

Comment: For now I decided to do something like so: `template.render(data).replace(/\n+/g, "\n")`

Comment: In fact `{{* ...}}`, for example, does not render anything - no newline, nothing. But if you add a newline before or after it, that is part of the template, and will be output.